What makes a curve a good fit in the context of logistic regression
As I wanted to gain a better intuition between why separation is a problem in the context of logistic regression, I did create in R two models, one where y is perfectly separated at $x=5$, and one which is not. For reproducibility, here is the generated dataset and the code used to generate estimation of various curves with a range of beta (with a same intercept) with the addition of the ML estimator and plotted everything along with the data points:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(boot)
library(tidyr)

df_sep <- data.frame(x=seq(0,9.9,by=0.1),y=c(rep(0,50),rep(1,50)))
df_notsep <- data.frame(x=seq(0,9.9,by=0.1),y=c(rbinom(50,1,0.2),rbinom(50,1,0.8)))

mod_sep <- glm(y~x,df_sep,family="binomial")
# (Intercept)           x 
# -1650.0708    333.3476 
df_sep <- df_sep %>% mutate(y_beta100= inv.logit(coef(mod_sep)[1]+100*x), 
                 y_beta200=inv.logit(coef(mod_sep)[1]+200*x), 
                 y_beta300=inv.logit(coef(mod_sep)[1]+300*x),
                 y_beta400=inv.logit(coef(mod_sep)[1]+400*x))
df_sep$y_pred <- predict(mod_sep,type="response")

df_sep_long <- df_sep %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("y"))

mod_notsep <- glm(y~x,df_notsep,family="binomial")
# (Intercept)           x 
# -2.5422783   0.5515725 

df_notsep <- df_notsep %>% mutate(y_beta0_2=inv.logit(coef(mod_notsep)[1]+0.2*x), 
                    y_beta0_3=inv.logit(coef(mod_notsep)[1]+0.3*x),
                    y_beta0_5=inv.logit(coef(mod_notsep)[1]+0.5*x),
                    y_beta0_7=inv.logit(coef(mod_notsep)[1]+0.7*x))

df_notsep$y_pred <- predict(mod_notsep,type="response")

df_notsep_long <- df_notsep %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("y"))


ggplot(df_sep_long, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = name, shape=name, group = name)) + 
  geom_point(data=df_sep_long %>% filter(name=="y"),alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_path(data=df_sep_long %>% filter(name!="y"), aes(x = x, y = value, colour = name, group = name)) +
  theme_bw()

ggplot(df_notsep_long, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = name, shape=name, group = name)) + 
  geom_point(data=df_notsep_long %>% filter(name=="y"),alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_path(data=df_notsep_long %>% filter(name!="y"), aes(x = x, y = value, colour = name, group = name)) +
  theme_bw()

I didn't understand better the convergence issue in the separated data, but on the other hand, was able to visualise why the predicted beta provides the maximum likelihood in that context, due to it being almost a piecewise function, and so it is clear that it is the value that allows the shortest line between the $\max{x}$ with a value of $y=0$ and the $\min{x}$ with a value of $y=1$.
However, for the non-separated data, it does not look obvious to me why the ML is the best fit. If we had an OLS, we would try to minimise the distance between the points and the line which is easy to fathom, but what are we exactly doing here when estimating the $\beta$ that maximise the likelihood function?



Please explain what your various curves are doing: their meanings are opaque.  After all, you present one (simulated) dataset but multiple curves: why do they vary?

Oh sorry for the lack of clarity, these are all inverse logit curves of various betas lower and higher than the optimal beta (that is portrayed as ypred). I wanted a visual comparison in order to understand what makes the optimal beta the ones with the ML, but failed to see why it was the case. Is it still the distance between the points and the curve that is indirectly minimised?

No, the likelihood is maximized.  That's what the "ML" in "ML estimator" means!  Check out our threads on this topic for more information.
